# How to utilize the free water from my well drawn sprinkler pump

Tags: pump, hose

My pump drawn sprinkler system has a spigot for a garden hose. Can I use it to water my plants or wash my car, pressure wash my driveway, top off my pool, hose off the boat?  I see this as a big money saving possibility.   If so, how do I do it? For instance, do I run my sprinkler system in a certain zone and simply turn the handle on the spigot?

Comment: This well water is not treated and so is not potable so I don't think you should use it to top off the pool, but the other uses you listed sound fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

We would need more information about this "well" if it is a true ground water well of course you can do anything with it , I have a well we drink from and water the lawn and water the horses, if it is just a in ground water storage of rain water still filling the pool watering the lawn and washing the cars is fine but I would not drink or water livestock without having it checked surface ground water has lots of nastys that are filtered out in most wells but not in ground water recovery systems.